# SSIS: need to use SQL query results in other SQL queries for data

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am trying to create an SSIS package for bringing over a subset of data into a separate reporting environment (basically from one data mart into another).

There are multiple tables I need to bring data from, but there is 1 initial source table I use to filter the records which belong to my group.

I am trying to figure out how to use the results from the first query as part of the subsequent queries. I have the first query returning just a single column (LookupID value) but it is going to have multiple rows.

My goal was to have multiple data ODB Source/Destination packages (one for each table) using the LookupID values to just grab the relevant records for me. But I cannot seem to find a way to do that natively.

My fall back is just to get all of the new records then delete within my staging tables but am hoping there is another/better method.

Comment: If you can use source table in a join that would be the ideal way. You may create several view for the each sources joining the initial source?

Comment: Within a single query yes. But then I would have to return it as one very large data set within SSIS then possibly split it out from the one ODB Source out to multiple ODB Destinations and split the data to each table it should go to. I'm also would be concerned that joining all of the tables together into one query would perform well.

Comment: I cannot create a custom view on the source server either.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to get there.

**Brute Force**

Inside your Data Flow Task (DFT), you *could* repeat your initial query in a `Lookup Transformation`. Lookups support a multi-column result set. Flow the data from the Source into the Lookup, and then on the `Columns` tab, pick your outputs.

**Moderately More Elegant**

If you capture that initial query as a `VIEW` in your database, you could use that view as the source for, again, a `Lookup Transformation`. That way, you only have one place to maintain it if the underlying query needs to change down the road.

**The Way I'd Probably Start**

The problem with Lookups is they consume memory. If your look up source is a few hundred, or even a few thousand rows, not really an issue. But if you're up over, say, 3-5 million records, it can start to really impact your application server and strain memory.

With that in mind, I'd lean toward, again, capturing the logic in a view, but then join to the view in the ODBC Source query. That shifts the heavy lifting back onto the SQL Server box, which is designed to do just that sort of work, and leaves SSIS to handle the data transfer, which it's excellent at handling.

Comment: Brute Force:
Does that need to be done for each of the tables I want to check? I will look into it though it sounds like it is puling the data then doing a comparison within SSIS? Perhaps I am understanding it wrong, I can try and take a look at that Lookup Transformation later today.

Moderately More Elegant/Way to start:
Unfortunately this is a very large central data mart used by the entire company, I don't have access to add/modify to it (ie: creating a view) which is part of the reason I am copying data to another server that I have more control over.

Comment: The Brute Force way would, yes, have to be done for each table. Tedious. You could pull the first query and use that to populate a table in your target database, then use that table as the basis for all the lookups. One of SSIS's strengths is it's ability to work across servers (by pulling all the data onto a app server, but just the same...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the results of your first lookup into an object variable and then parse through that at later steps. Most probably it would be a combination of getting the data into an object variable (Execute sql task), then a for each loop container per subsequent table to 'Lookup' the values from this object variable. This is only high level that I am describing without actually getting into the details about your data.

If you have high volume of data, then maybe I would stick with Eric's last approach.

Comment: I was looking for more of a way to utilize the initial recordset/object within the query. Looping is too slow and tedious. Even if it was a small data set for that day it would still be more efficient to pull all of the data to the other SQL server and cleanup records there within the staging schema I have setup.

Comment: I was hoping there was a method for utilizing the first object/recordset as part of the query in the other sections. I kind of assumed when I was struggling to google it that this may not be possible but wanted to check in case.